# reloading tableview and touch gestures

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitouch

I have a tableview which is being reloaded as new content is added, using `[tableview reloadData];`

Trouble is I have a UILongPressGestureRecognizer on the TableCells in the Table and because the cells / table are being reloaded quite often the LongPress doesnt always have time to work as, I'm guessing it's internal timers are being reset when the cell/table is being reloaded.

Comment: What is the frequency of updates?

Comment: What kind of changes are happening on the cells? Does the whole table change, or just one cell at the time?

Comment: The tables datasource being added to and when it is the tableviewcontroller is calling [tableview reloadData] which reloads the table / adds a cell to the bottom of the table.

Comment: What problems do you have, and what *should* happen?

Comment: Is there no way of detecting if the user has placed a finger on the device? That way I can stop reloadData being called until the finger is lifted...

Comment: Referring to your latest question daidai; see octy's answer - check for the `UIGestureRecognizer.state` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the state of your `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`s before `[tableView reloadData]` is called? For example:

```
// Returns |YES| if a gesture recognizer began detecting a long tap gesture
- (BOOL)longTapPossible {
    BOOL possible = NO;

    UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = nil;
    NSArray *visibleIndexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visibleIndexPaths) {
        // I suppose you have only one UILongPressGestureRecognizer per cell
        gestureRecognizer = [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] gestureRecognizers] 
                                lastObject];
        possible = (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
                    gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged);
        if (possible) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return possible;
}

// ... later, where you reload the tableView:

if ([self longTapPossible] == NO) {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: +1 for suggesting the inspection of `UIGestureRecognizer.state`

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `reloadData` if you want existing cells to remain. Instead, when you get new data, use the methods for [Inserting and Deleting Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW53) to inform the table view exactly which cells have changed. The general procedure is:

1. You get new data.
2. Call `beginUpdates`
3. Call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to remove cells for any old items that have been deleted in the new data.
4. Call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to add new cells for any items that have been added in the new data.
5. If you need to selectively replace a particular cell for some reason (and can't just update the existing cell's subviews with the new data), use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.
6. Call `commitUpdates`. At this point, your `UITableViewDataSource` methods must reflect the new data (e.g. `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` should reflect the changed count, and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should use the new items).
7. The table view will now call your data source methods as needed to update the display. Existing rows will not be changed.

Comment: I have tried this technique in the past and found that the reloadData method was much better for my system. Is there no way of detecting if the user have place a finger on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Set a BOOL like aCellIsSelected to YES when you touch the cell

and just reload tableview if aCellIsSelected is NO

Comment: The trouble with this is that the UILongPressGestureRecognizer doesnt get fired until the a 'long' time has passed. And I cant listen for the didSelectRowAtIndexPath as this is a tap and is not a press, so it doesnt get called either.

Comment: You can subclass UITableViewCell and in set the value in setHighlighted